# Need help setting up & selling theater tickets using Square APIs

Tags: square-connect

I run a website for a local children's theater. We are migrating from PayPal to Square for all our ticket sales and other payment needs. I have absolutely no idea how to get started or what would be the best option for us for selling tickets online.

I have looked at the API documentation, I have asked on Seller Community, and I have been on the Square Slack channel. As far as I can tell, the Checkout API seems to be my best bet, but I don't understand how to use it.

If anyone has experience using Square to sell theater tickets or something similar, I would really appreciate some input.

For reference, here is the page I need to migrate from PayPal: https://talespinnerchildrenstheatre.org/tickets/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the square checkout api.
You will need to sends the order information to Square and you will receive a URL (hosted in square server ) to the Square Checkout UI. Refer the below documentation for further information.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/checkout/overview

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-checkout

If you are intend to use php here is the sdk and the samples.

https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk

https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Api/CheckoutApi.md#createcheckout